# Jersey client get sent data to String

Tags: java, json, junit, junit4

I am building some JUnit tests for a REST client using Jersey, I therefore need to have a copy of the data sent to the server to run some tests in JUnit.

Currently my clients invokes:

```
Invocation invocation = serviceWebTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                        buildPut(Entity.json((QARecord) valuesList.get(0)));
Response response = invocation.invoke();
```

In between the two calls the QARecord object is serialized to JSON and sent to the server but I cannot find a way to access it.
By debugging the code I found no variable in either invocation or response which contains the converted JSON text.

How can get the sent data into a String or a File for my JUnit test to check what has been sent?

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you want to check what exactly client will sent to server as a request, am i right ? 
If yes how exactly does your Unit test look like ?

For instance Jersey provides [**JerseyTest**](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/test/JerseyTest.html) class which is base for testing of client code.

In few words such test will run special testcontainer which is able to execute your handlers inside. 
By combining it with Mockito / or creating your own handlers by yourself, you can verify what is "captured" by them as a client request at the end of the test (when response is received by client). Among others it'll give you possibility to check not only what your client code is sending to server but also check behaviour of client by emulating various responses (successful or exceptional).

If you just want to get content of what client is really send to the server you can write jersey client filter and get body of request from there.
[Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)